# Piping in and out of tar and gzip

Tags: linux, filesystems, compression, zfs

I am trying to get a handle on how to pipe from a command into something like gzip, cpio or tar.

The commands in question belong to the ZFS system. I am running ZFS on Ubuntu Linux 10.04.3.

The commands I working with are;

```
To create a snapshot;
zfs snapshot media/mypictures@20070607

To copy the snapshot to a directory;
zfs send media/mypictures@20070607 > ~/backups/20070607

Then I can also pipe into gzip
zfs send media/mypictures@20070607 | gzip > ~/backups/20070607.gz
```

These parts I understand.

But my first question is, what would I do to pipe into tar + gzip?

This?

```
zfs send media/mypictures@20070607 | tar czvf > ~/backups/20070607.tar.gz
```

And my other question is how would I get the data out of the tarball or gzip?

I have to use `zfs recieve media/mypictures@20070607 < ~/backups/20070607`

So would it just be this if I was using tar?

```
zfs recieve media/mypictures@20070607 | tar xzvf < ~/backups/20070607.tar.gz
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`tar` expects to be given a list of filenames as command line arguments. So far as I know, it cannot be used to read an anonymous pipeline (what would it store as filename and file-metadata?)

```
$ echo aaa | tar cv > f.tar
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try `tar --help' for more information.
```

If your data is a single logical item or stream, there is no need to use something like tar, which is used to group together a set of separate files.

Otherwise you will have to write the data to a file first, tar the file, then delete the file.

Comment: Really? I though tar was just another form of compression. So skip tar and just gzip?

Comment: Yes, just use `zfs send media/mypictures@20070607 | gzip -c > ~/backups/20070607.gz`

Comment: Tar DOES NOT expect a list of file names unless you specify the `-f` option (tar also accepts `f` without the "-").

Comment: @drevicko: The context of the question is creating a tar archive. The list of files I mean is the list of files (and/or directories) to be included in the written archive. For example: `cd /etc; TAPE=/tmp/rgb.tar tar c hosts passwd` where the list of files is `hosts passwd`

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick but the context of the question is to tar from a pipe, ie: no list of files. Saying tar expects a list of files is not true. The problem is that it expects a (single) output file name when the OP specifies `f`, and he didn't provide it.

Answer (score 10):

The `-f` option specifies a file, else the output goes to stdout. So, either drop the redirection:

```
zfs send media/mypictures@20070607 | tar czvf ~/backups/20070607.tar.gz
```

Or drop the `f` option:

```
zfs send media/mypictures@20070607 | tar czv > ~/backups/20070607.tar.gz
```

Similarly with untarring.

Comment: Does this actually work? Both `echo "hello" | tar czvf foo.tar.gz` and `echo "hello" | tar czv > foo.tar.gz` fail for me.